# IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match 'kid'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, key, openid-connect, keycloak

My goal is to authorize a page of application with Keycloak.
I have an MVC .net 4.5 application who is using KEYCLOAK and i cant find a solution for this problem:

In this link 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/certs' i can see my kid, who is using RS256 algorithm but the error is telling me i should match the HS256 algorithm.

I dont understand why is checking different key of the same client???
May i need to fix the same key? if yes where?

I have a startup.cs like this one:
https://github.com/dylanplecki/KeycloakOwinAuthentication/wiki/ASP.NET-MVC-Tutorial
I've addes the DisableAudienceValidation to true and a callback path to page

And into the Keycloak side i have done some basic setup from the tutorial of the 4.8.3 version with the 'Standard flow enabled' only.

Please, any tips will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: We have the same issue here. Isn't any solution for that? Maybe the better attempt is to use IdentityServer...

Comment: @physox Actually we didn't find any solution to be able to use the class 'Authorize' using the Startup.cs to initialize Keycloak, so for the moment we are using the 'JS adapter' but i will edit my question if i'll find a solution.